# after upgrade, react native still showed the old version number

Tags: react-native

I want to make sure I have latest react native before starting a new project.

```
"react-native --version" returned back 0.1.5
```

then i upgraded it using `npm install --save react-native@0.18.1`.  but it still showed `0.1.5`.

Why its not showing the latest version number?

Answer (score 1):

`react-native --version` is going to give you the version of the [react native cli](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-cli) you have installed globally.

If you want to find out the version of react-native in your app configuration, open package.json in your root directory and look for a line that looks like this:

```
"react-native": "^0.13.0"
```

To get the exact version you have installed in your app, you can go in your node_modules and find the react-native package and open your package.json. Look for a line that looks like this (usually at the bottom or top ime):

`"version": "0.13.2"`